# How to access array inside an array of Objects React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm working on react e-commerce project as a learning process and stuck in a situation where I have array of orders which contains multiple order objects, and inside order there's an array of OrderItems containing orderItem objects.

Here's the Array structure of two orders for reference.

```
myOrders: [
  {
    id: 1,
    order_items: [
      {
        prod_id: 1,
        name: 123,
        qty: 1,
      },
      {
        prod_id: 1,
        name: 123,
        qty: 1,
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    order_items: [
      {
        prod_id: 4,
        name: "xyz",
        qty: 2,
      },
      {
        prod_id: 5,
        name: "abc",
        qty: 5,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

How do I access order_items for all orders respectively?
What I have tried so far is:
Retrieved myOrders from reducer using useSelector, then destructured it to get order_items and used

> order_items.map()

function, but it throws an error saying

> Can't find map of undefined

I'm learning React JS and not an expert yet. Would really appreciate any kind of help from all the experts out there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The destructuring is most likely the problem; did you use `const { order_items } = myOrders`? Because you would need `const { order_items } = myOrders[i]` or (an outer `.map()` to iterate over myOrders)

Comment: Yes, I did use const { order_items } = myOrders

Comment: But there is no `myOrders.order_items`, since `myOrders` is an array.

Comment: So I need to iterate myOrders, and for each myOrders I have to get order_items. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Two nested map()s are ideal here.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath.'s answer solved my problem. You may refer to that one

Answer (score 1):

You can try `map` function on myOrders array to retrieve order_items and the flat those into 1 single array

```js
let myOrders = [
{
        id: 1,
        order_items: [
            {
                prod_id : 1,
                name: '123',
                qty: 1
            },
            {
                prod_id : 1,
                name: '123',
                qty: 1
            }
        ]       
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        order_items: [
            {
                prod_id : 4,
                name: 'xyz',
                qty: 2
            },
            {
                prod_id : 5,
                name: 'abc',
                qty: 5
            }
        ]       
    }

];

let result = myOrders.map(i => i.order_items).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. now I have to iterate result again and I'll have access to prod_id, name and qty. I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myOrders = [{id:1,order_items:[{prod_id:1,name:123,qty:1},{prod_id:1,name:123,qty:1}]},{id:2,order_items:[{prod_id:4,name:"xyz",qty:2},{prod_id:5,name:"abc",qty:5}]}];

const out = myOrders.reduce((a, b) => {
  a.push(...b.order_items);
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give it a try